# how this inequality holds?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

The answer says III is true because of the inequality above which I couldn't see. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have for $0\leq x\leq 1$

$$\frac{x^n}{1+1} \leq \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\leq \frac{x^n}{1+0}$$

Now, integrate this inequality.